Kafka topics partitions sync up after adding extra broker node
We are using Confluent Platform 5.5 community edition in our project with 4 broker and 3 zookeeper.
We would like to add one more broker in existing cluster. After adding broker how we can do sync up topics partitions with new broker node. Tried with confluent-rebalancer but its license product.
Any leads will be really helpful.

You would follow the documentation on expanding the cluster to use kafka-reassign-partitions command to manually specify all topics and partitions that you'd like to move.
Keep in mind,

The partition reassignment tool does not have the capability to automatically study the data distribution in a Kafka cluster and move partitions around to attain an even load distribution. As such, the admin has to figure out which topics or partitions should be moved around.

Some people use Cruise Control to help with this
